# Window preview is not working in DockbarX

Tags: 10.10, gnome, dockbarx

I have installed dockbarx using an article at omgubuntu. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/new-look-dockbarx-hits-ppa/. The problem is that the window preview feature is not working.

UPDATE: While running `dockbarx_factory.py run-in-window` , i get the following warning:

```
 ** (dockbarx_factory.py:3820): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'WnckWindowState' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'

** (dockbarx_factory.py:3820): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'WnckWindowActions' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'

** (dockbarx_factory.py:3820): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'WnckWindowMoveResizeMask' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'
Dockbarx init
Dockbarx reload
Opened window matched with gio app on id: empathy
Opened window matched with gio app on id: gnome-terminal
```

.

[image]

How can i enable the preview?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- To use the window previews,you need CompizConfig Settings Manager

  `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
- Warning: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)
- Also in gnome enable **KDE Compatibility** plugin  System>>Preferences>>CompizConfig Settings Manager.
- Once you enable this plugin, in DockBarX preferences goto Applications>>Accessories>>DockBarX>> Preference), on the **Window List** tab, enable **Show Previews**.

[image]

Comment: @karthik: Yes .I have already done this. Still the preview is not working.

Comment: Just to confirm, this did work for me.

Comment: @aneeshep Press **ALT+F2** and type the following without quotes "compiz --replace && killall gnome-panel"

Comment: @karthik: it is also not working. At last i got it working by reinstalling the os.

Comment: interesting answer for ubuntu but what about those running xfce or xubuntu? xfce comes with a compositor so there should be no need to run compiz. correct?

Answer (score 1):

I've just figured this out myself, so.

Open Compizconfig Settings Manager (System>>Preferences).

Navigate to tab "Extras".

Select "Window Previews".

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: @Valis: I have tried this too. But no use. Still i can't get the preview.

Comment: This does indeed show previews, however they're not the DockBarX integrated ones. For those, see karthick87's answer.